# Inserting a node into a Binary Tree using Level Order Traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to write a function that will insert an element into a Binary Tree using level order traversal. The issue i'm encountering with my code is that when I go to print the level order traversal after inserting a new node into the tree, it prints the elements in an infinite loop. The numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 keep racing across the terminal. I would appreciate any pointers and advice on how to remedy this situation.

```
typedef struct BinaryTreeNode {
    int data;
    BinaryTreeNode * left;
    BinaryTreeNode * right;
} BinaryTreeNode;
```

This is the level order traversal to print the elements:

```
void LevelOrder(BinaryTreeNode *root) {
BinaryTreeNode *temp;
std::queue<BinaryTreeNode*> Q {};

if(!root) return;

Q.push(root);

while(!Q.empty()) {
    temp = Q.front();
    Q.pop();

    //process current node
    printf("%d ", temp -> data);

    if(temp -> left) Q.push(temp -> left);
    if(temp -> right) Q.push(temp -> right);
}
}
```

This is where I insert an element into the tree by modifying level order traversal technique

```
void insertElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, int element) {
BinaryTreeNode new_node = {element, NULL, NULL};

BinaryTreeNode *temp;
std::queue<BinaryTreeNode*> Q {};

if(!root) {
   root = &new_node;
   return;
}

Q.push(root);

while(!Q.empty()) {
    temp = Q.front();
    Q.pop();

    //process current node
    if(temp -> left) Q.push(temp -> left);
    else {
        temp -> left = &new_node;
        Q.pop();
        return;
    }

    if(temp -> right) Q.push(temp -> right);
    else {
        temp -> right = &new_node;
        Q.pop();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

MAIN

```
int main() {
BinaryTreeNode one = {1, NULL, NULL}; // root of the binary tree
BinaryTreeNode two = {2, NULL, NULL};
BinaryTreeNode three = {3, NULL, NULL};
BinaryTreeNode four = {4, NULL, NULL};
BinaryTreeNode five = {5, NULL, NULL};
BinaryTreeNode six = {6, NULL, NULL};
BinaryTreeNode seven = {7, NULL, NULL};

one.left = &two;
one.right = &three;

two.left = &four;
two.right = &five;

three.left = &six;
three.right = &seven;

insertElementInBinaryTree(&one, 8);

LevelOrder(&one);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
    temp -> left = &new_node;
```

You are making `temp->left` point to a local variable, which will no longer exist after the function returns.  Any attempt to access it is undefined behavior.

Comment: So I should be sending in the node to be added instead of creating the node locally ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: That would be reasonable.

Comment: Just curious on how I could make it work by just sending in the actual element (the number) instead of creating the node in main.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: You would need to allocate it in a way that would persist after the function returns.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: Because the rest of your nodes are allocated on the stack in main(), it would be consistent to create the new node in main() as well, but alternatively, you could have something like a `std::list` of nodes.  Your insert function could be passed a reference to the list of nodes.  It would then add the new node to the list and get a pointer to it.